# What SIP header decides that a SIP MESSAGE should be treated as an SMS?

Tags: android, sms, sip

I know that in order to receive SMS Messages via SIP and so the device (phone) treats them using the SMS application, the registration to the SIP server should be done using `+g.3gpp.smsip` feature tag in the `Contact:` header.

**Register request**

```
REGISTER sip:*** SIP/2.0
...
Contact: <sip:***>;...;+g.3gpp.smsip;...
...
```

indicating that the device is capable of accepting SMS messages via SIP.

What is required in the MESSAGE request to send a simple text message as a SMS message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but this is a bit more complex that what you've in mind. Let me try to clarify it:

Adding +g.3gpp.smsip parameter to REGISTER's contact header indicates that you're supporting SMS encapsulation inside SIP MESSAGE request. If this is actually what you want to achieve, to send and SMS your MESSAGE should contain:

- Request URI containing your S-CSCF's public service identity (this depends on your operator).
- To header also containing your network provider's S-CSCF's PSI.
- A `Content-Type: application/vnd.3gpp.sms` header.
- The body of the request should contain SMS RP-DATA (including SMS headers and info).

On the other hand, if what you want to achieve, as you states in our question, is sending a plain text MESSAGE request and receive a SMS, then, you need that your network provider supports SIP gateway to GSM services. If this is what you're looking for, I think that, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19502482/1419134) will help you.