# Sip Error while registration

Tags: java, android, sip

I am using native methods of sip calling and it is working fine but some time it is giving registration error IN_PROGRESS (Error Code -9 ) .I have search in Sip Error codes but dint find any error code of this kind . Here is my code for sip registration .PLease tell me if any one have idea about this error please tell me .

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.net.sip.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
/**
 * Handles all calling, receiving calls, and UI interaction in the WalkieTalkie app.
 */
public class WalkieTalkieActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public String sipAddress = null;
    public static SipManager manager = null;
    public static SipProfile me = null;
    public SipAudioCall call = null;
    public SipErrorCode sipcode;
    public SipException sipexeception;
    public static WalkieTalkieActivity walkiy;

    public static WalkieTalkieActivity getInstance() {
        if (walkiy == null) {
            walkiy = new WalkieTalkieActivity();
        }
        return walkiy;
    }

    @
    Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        Log.e("onCreate", "onCreate");
        initializeManager(this);
    }

    @
    Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // When we get back from the preference setting Activity, assume
        // settings have changed, and re-login with new auth info.
    }

    @
    Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    @
    Override
    protected void onResume() {
        initializeManager(this);
        super.onResume();
    }

    public void initializeManager(Context ctx) {

        Log.e("inilitize", "initialize manager");

        if (manager == null) {
            manager = SipManager.newInstance(ctx);

        }
        initializeLocalProfile(ctx);
    }

    /**
     * Logs you into your SIP provider, registering this device as the location to
     * send SIP calls to for your SIP address.
     */
    public void initializeLocalProfile(final Context ctx) {
        Log.e("inilitize", "initialize profile");
        if (manager == null) {

            Log.e("inilitize", "return in profile");
            updateStatus("we are unable to establish this feature on your device ", ctx);
            Log.e("Wifi state", "" + SipManager.isSipWifiOnly(ctx));
            return;
        }
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        String username = prefs.getString("namePref", "XYZ");
        String domain = prefs.getString("domainPref", "236.343.230.2");
        String password = prefs.getString("passPref", "XYZ");

        try {
            Log.e("inilitize", "building profile ");
            SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
            builder.setPassword(password);
            me = builder.build();
            manager.open(me);

            Log.e("alredy registered1", "" + manager.isRegistered(me.getUriString()));
            try {
                if (manager.isRegistered(me.getUriString())) {

                    Log.e("alredy registered2", "" + manager.isRegistered(me.getUriString()));
                    updateStatus("Ready", ctx);
                    return;
                }

            } catch (SipException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                closeLocalProfile();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {

                    Log.e("Sip restration", "Registering with SIP Server..." + me.getUriString());
                    updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...", ctx);
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    Log.e("Sip restration", "Ready");
                    updateStatus("Ready", ctx);

                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                    String errorMessage) {
                    Log.e("Error Code Registration ", SipErrorCode.toString(errorCode) + " " + errorCode);
                    updateStatus(SipErrorCode.toString(errorCode), ctx);
                }
            });
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            updateStatus("Connection Error.", ctx);
        } catch (SipException se) {
            updateStatus("Connection error.", ctx);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes out your local profile, freeing associated objects into memory
     * and unregistering your device from the server.
     */
    public void closeLocalProfile() {
        if (manager == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (me != null) {
                manager.unregister(me, new SipRegistrationListener() {

                    @
                    Override
                    public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                        String errorMessage) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("unregister failed", "unregister failed");

                    }

                    @
                    Override
                    public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("unregister done", "unregister done");
                    }

                    @
                    Override
                    public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Log.e("unregistering", "unregistering");
                    }
                });
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make an outgoing call.
     */
    public void initiateCall(String number, final Context ctx, final View v) {


        Log.d("Number", "" + number);
        sipAddress = number;

        Log.e("initiating call", "initiating call");
        try {



            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {@
                Override
                public void onCallBusy(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("buzy", "buzy");
                    super.onCallBusy(call);
                }

                @
                Override
                public void onCallHeld(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("held", "held");
                    super.onCallHeld(call);
                }

                @
                Override
                public void onCalling(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("calling", "calling");
                    super.onCalling(call);
                }

                @
                Override
                public void onChanged(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("changed", "changed");
                    super.onChanged(call);
                }

                @
                Override
                public void onError(SipAudioCall call, int errorCode,
                    String errorMessage) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.e("call error", "error" + SipErrorCode.toString(errorCode) + " " + errorCode);
                    CallingScreen.fa.finish();
                    super.onError(call, errorCode, errorMessage);
                }

                @
                Override
                public void onReadyToCall(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("ready to call", "ready to call ");
                    super.onReadyToCall(call);
                }

                @
                Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("ringing", "ringing");

                    super.onRinging(call, caller);
                }

                @
                Override
                public void onRingingBack(SipAudioCall call) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.e("ringing back", "ringing back");

                    super.onRingingBack(call);
                }

                // Much of the client's interaction with the SIP Stack will
                // happen via listeners.  Even making an outgoing call, don't
                // forget to set up a listener to set things up once the call is established.
                @
                Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {

                    Log.e("call established", "call established");
                    call.startAudio();
                    updateTime(true, ctx);
                }

                @
                Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    Log.e("call ended", "call ended");

                    updateTime(false, ctx);
                    CallingScreen.fa.finish();
                }
            };

            Log.e("param 1 ", "" + me.getUriString());
            call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress + "@216.245.200.2:5060", listener, 30);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall", "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
            if (me != null) {
                try {
                    closeLocalProfile();
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                        "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (call != null) {
                call.close();
            }
        }
    }


    public void updateStatus(final String status, final Context context) {
        // Be a good citizen.  Make sure UI changes fire on the UI thread.
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                generateNotification(context, status);

            }
        });
    }

    public void updateTime(final Boolean status, final Context context) {
        // Be a good citizen.  Make sure UI changes fire on the UI thread.
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                if (status) {
                    CallingScreen.fa.calling_screen_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    CallingScreen.fa.ch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    CallingScreen.fa.ch.start();
                } else {
                    CallingScreen.fa.ch.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void updateStatus(SipAudioCall call) {
        String useName = call.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();
        if (useName == null) {
            useName = call.getPeerProfile().getUserName();
        }
        //      updateStatus(useName + "@" + call.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain());
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (call == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && call != null && call.isMuted()) {
            call.toggleMute();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !call.isMuted()) {
            call.toggleMute();
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void speaker(Boolean state) {
        if (call != null)
            call.setSpeakerMode(state);
    }

    public void endcall() {
        if (call != null) {
            try {
                call.endCall();
            } catch (SipException se) {
                Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onOptionsItemSelected",
                    "Error ending call.", se);
            }
            call.close();
        }
    }

    public static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        Log.e("inilitize", "generate notification");
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Splash_screen.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SIP is a transaction based protocol, this means, every negotiation process is a transaction (e.g. a basic registration process would imply sending a REISTER request and receive 200 OK response). I posted a small example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20443357/1419134) response.

IN_PROGRESS error initially indicates that you tried to start a new transaction, in your scenario you're trying to send a REGISTER request, when client is already in another related one.

A quite typical scenario is, in a fast logout/login, trying to register when unregistration process is still running (no 200 OK final response has been received).

Main problem regarding Android's SIP implementation and this error code is that it's used when as generic error when processing a SIP request fails so, previous meaning loses its significance.

Because of previous problem you would need to check logcat to get more information (you should see something like "~~~~~ SipSessionGroup:: processing ") but, best way to handle this, would be working with different listeners provided by the stack.

The stack provides two listeners that can get registration errors: [SipRegistrationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipRegistrationListener.html) and [SipSession.Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipSession.Listener.html). Both provides [onRegistrationFailed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipRegistrationListener.html#onRegistrationFailed%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29) callback but, later one, also provides [onRegistrationTimeout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipSession.Listener.html#onRegistrationTimeout%28android.net.sip.SipSession%29), that can be quite helpful. Actually, you already used SipRegistrationListener in your code but I don't really get why you say that it should be set after `open` because `open` would try to automatically register and, if some error occurs, you won't be notified.

On the other hand, main problem with this listeners is that registration can fail because of several reason (you can check a list of different error responses [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIP_Responses#4xx.E2.80.94Client_Failure_Responses)) and current implementation only notifies of error codes >= 500 (those are server and global failures) but not others like quite common 406. This is, in my opinion, an important bug in this stack.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering but can you please explain what should I do now to avoid this

Comment: Seriously I appreciate knowledge on this topic but I am using it first time and this is also sample code from sdk .So please can you explain in little bit easily :( also I want to know I can get this error list.It will be helpful to me if you can share that

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha Sure, no problem, sorry if I've been too direct. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I am getting errors whose code are -9 , -4 etc can I get list of this errors ?

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipErrorCode.html) you've a list of different errors coming from Android's SIP stack.

Comment: Can you please see my updated code once it is giving CLIENT_ERROR :(

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha I'm really sorry but, T should confirm that you were right from the beginning: I've checked stack's source code and there is a bug for calls to `open` providing a listener. This is the reason for the CLIENT_ERROR you're facing. So you should rollback to setting the listener after calling to `open`. On the other hand, I think that your problem is actually that `close` is not deregistering the user. Can you call `manager.unregister` before closing and check if this helps?

Comment: Actually I am not able to unregister as it is giving error        12-17 14:13:55.881: D/WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy(12747): Failed to close local profile.
12-17 14:13:55.881: D/WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy(12747): android.net.sip.SipException: SipService.createSession() returns null

Comment: Same problem, when i am trying to call unregister SipService.createSession() returns null.