# sip registration failure - tried 3 diff. account

Tags: java, android

I need to include a walki talkie in my app.  I am always getting a registration failure -9 error code.  I created 2 free Sip account (sip2sip.info, sip.linphone.org) and 1 commercial one (onsip.com).  I added all those permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

and the following features:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

I am calling the above fonction in the onCreate:

```
void log_and_register()
{
    try
    {
        c.DEBUG().ftrace("VOIP Supported: " + SipManager.isVoipSupported(c.ma()));
        c.DEBUG().ftrace("SIP API Supported: " + SipManager.isApiSupported(c.ma()));

        mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(c.ma());
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(c.config().getSIP_UserName(), c.config().getSIP_Domain());
        builder.setPassword(c.config().getSIP_Password());

        //builder.setProtocol("UDP"); //"TCP");
        //builder.setPort(5060);   //5080  5070   
        builder.setAutoRegistration(true);

        mSipProfile = builder.build();
    }
    catch (ParseException pe)
    {
        c.DEBUG().ftrace("incapable of parsing domain name, username or password!");
        c.DEBUG().ASSERT(0 == 1);
    }

    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c.ma(), 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, null);
    }
    catch (SipException se)
    {
        c.DEBUG().ftrace("WALKIE TALKIE NOT WORKING - Sip Exception!!");
        c.DEBUG().ASSERT(0 == 1);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(c.ma(), Manifest.permission.USE_SIP) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        c.DEBUG().ftrace("GRANTED!!!");
    else
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(c.ma(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.USE_SIP}, 1);

    try
    {
        if (mSipManager.isRegistered(mSipProfile.getUriString()))
        {
            c.DEBUG().ftrace("already registered !!" + mSipManager.isRegistered(mSipProfile.getUriString()));
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        c.DEBUG().ftrace("NO!!");
    }



    try
    {
        //mSipManager.register(mSipProfile, 30, new SipRegistrationListener(){
        //mSipManager.register(mSipProfile, 30000, new SipRegistrationListener(){

        c.DEBUG().ftrace("THIS IS THE TRACE BEFORE REGISTATION : " + mSipProfile.getUriString());
        mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener()
        {
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri)
            {
                c.DEBUG().ftrace("Registering with SIP Server...");
            }

            // next version has it!!
            public void onRegistrationTimeout() {}

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime)
            {
                c.DEBUG().ftrace("SIP Ready");
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage)
            {
                // -9 signifie qu'il y a un appel en cours
                c.DEBUG().ftrace("CANNOT REGISTER domain=" + c.config().getSIP_Domain() + " / username=" + c.config().getSIP_UserName());
                c.DEBUG().ftrace("SIP ERROR MSG : localProfileUri=" + localProfileUri + "   errorCode=" + errCode(errorCode) + "  errorMessage=" + errorMessage);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        c.DEBUG().ftrace("Cannot initialise wakie talkie!");
        c.DEBUG().ASSERT(0 == 1);
    }


    // https:github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/commit/a025796211f15c2796f8ea3208c066801aa250b6
    initiateCall();
}

public SipAudioCall call = null;
public void initiateCall() {

    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            // Much of the client's interaction with the SIP Stack will
            // happen via listeners.  Even making an outgoing call, don't
            // forget to set up a listener to set things up once the call is established.
            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                call.toggleMute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
            }
        };

        c.DEBUG().ftrace("rafael - Format="+mSipProfile.getUriString());
        //call = mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 30);
        call = mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(), "sip:rafael.hogue@sip2sip.info", listener, 30);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall", "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
        if (mSipProfile != null) {
            try {
                mSipManager.close(mSipProfile.getUriString());
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                        "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I compile for Nougat because I am using deprecated function.  Then I modified my code to compile with Oreo. 
I used Firewall Voip Checker to check my connection with my SIP server and the test 1 is successful but the second one seam to be in an infinite loop.  One of the result of the test one is captured my attention but I don't know what it means:

Check NAT type

100% / Blocked or could not reach STUN server (but it's green so I guess it pass the test??).  I had the flag :

android.useDeprecatedNdk=true

I change it to false... 
and I always get the return code "registration faild"

I hadded this fonction to see what the -9 error code was:

// FOR MORE DETAILS SEE
// [Sip Error while registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563566/sip-error-while-registration)
// [How to send instant message via SIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502482/how-to-send-instant-message-via-sip/20443357#20443357)
//https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipErrorCode
    private String errCode(int iErrorCode)
    {
        String sErr = "";

```
    switch (iErrorCode)
    {
        case CLIENT_ERROR:
            sErr = "client error!!";
            break;
        case CROSS_DOMAIN_AUTHENTICATION:
            sErr = "cross domain authentification!!";
            break;
        case DATA_CONNECTION_LOST:
            sErr = "data connection lost!!";
            break;
        case INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
            sErr = "invalid credentials!!";
            break;
        case INVALID_REMOTE_URI:
            sErr = "invalid remote uri!!";
            break;
        case IN_PROGRESS:
            sErr = "In progress!!";
            break;
        case NO_ERROR:
            sErr = "No error!!";
            break;
        case PEER_NOT_REACHABLE:
            sErr = "peer not reachable!!";
            break;
        case SERVER_ERROR:
            sErr = "server error!!";
            break;
        case SERVER_UNREACHABLE:
            sErr = "server unreachable!!";
            break;
        case SOCKET_ERROR:
            sErr = "socket error!!";
            break;
        case TIME_OUT:
            sErr = "time out!!";
            break;
        case TRANSACTION_TERMINTED:
            sErr = "No transaction terminated!!";
            break;
        default:
            sErr = "No error detected!!";
            break;
    }

    return (sErr);
}
```

The error message is "In progress..." witch means that he is busy already but I don't know what it means.

I when thru the error code on Wikipedia to have clues of the potential problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes#4xx.E2.80.94Client_Failure_Responses

I tried to find a SDK of a higher lever to implement my walki talki and found.

I search for the app wireshark but I only found it for a laptop and not for my android smartphone.

It's important for me to implement the walki talkie because I am creating a app to increase the security of primary school daycare and we need to communicate with each other.

I tried to change the port and the communication protocol and I tried the AutoRegistration flag to true.

I tried to make a phone call after the registration failed in case the open statement did the registration assuming it could be trying to register a second time.

I have no more idea!!

Comment: After a quick look I only saw in `log_and_register()` that there is `builder.setAutoRegistration(true);` and the next line is `SipProfile.Builder builder = ...` which creates a local variable shadowing the instance variable.

Comment: I reedited and problem you pointed out (thanks!) and retested port 5060, 5080, AutoRegistration set to true or commented out and I still get a registration failure.

Comment: @Rafael SIP is commonly `5060` (plain) and `5061` (SSL). try connecting with telnet for a test. make sure the device does not have the SIP account added and possibly already registered. there is no WireShark for Android, while it does not matter while being on the same network segment and the notebook's NIC does support promiscuous mode (if the WiFi doesn't, use cable and the router).

Comment: … I continue searching and I am considering implementing a WIFI Walki-Talki without a sip accout.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176988/android-voip-application-without-access-to-internet

Comment: I will save the port information and ip adresse of every android device into my firebase database on startup in order to establish communication without asking anything to the user to make it automatique.

Answer (score 0):

I will implementing a WIFI Walki Talki without a sip account. 
Reference: stackoverflow.com/questions/11176988/…

Then I will save, on startup, the port information, ip adresse, username of every smart phones (use by my collegue) into my firebase (online database) in order to establish communication without asking anything to the user to make it automatique.

I am realizing that if I have trouble connecting with sample code that is suppose to work this probably means that my clients will have the same kinds of problemes wish I want to avoid.

I don't need to communicate with people that are not on the same network but I think this method would also work over the internet even for cliente that are on an other router if they are all connected to the internet.